# Firebase SignOut returning null on GetCurrentUser.GetUid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

im having a little problem, in my `onStop` from my `MainActivity` im uploading to firebase some data, so, if i switch to my logout activity fast and press `SignOut`, i perform a `SignOut`, but at the time im Signing out the data is still uploading, so , when i Sign Out i get my GetCurrentUser = null , so the data cant still uploading and my app crashes, in my logout i want to check if the user had uploaded all before logout, i added `onCompletionListeners` in my `MainActivity.class`, so i can handle if the user is null, but it keeps crashing, i think i need to do a checkout before i press the SignOut button, so, i check if the data is all uploaded and then LogOut, im beign arround this problem for the past week and its getting annoying.

Here is my Uploadings in `MainActivity.class`

```
myref.putStream(groups)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrlGrupos = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                                        mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("groups").setValue(downloadUrlGrupos.toString(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference groupsReference) {
                                                if(groupsReference!=null){
                                                    Log.d("TAG", "Se guardo correctamente url Grupos");
                                                }else
                                                {
                                                    Log.d("TAG", "Error al subir url Grupos");
                                                }


                                            }
                                        }); 





                                }
```

And this is my SignOut Button in my Other Class

```
  button.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {


                   //I think here need to be a check , so i first check if all the data is uploaded to firebase, and then SignOut


                         Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {

                                 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                                 mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                                 finish();
                             }
                         });
```

whole OnStop

```
 @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();


                   if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){





                    referenciaGrupos.putStream(g)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrlG = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                                        mDatabase.child("user").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("URL_g").setValue(downloadUrlG.toString(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference referenciaG) {
                                                if(referenciaG!=null){
                                                    Log.d("TAG", "Se guardo correctamente url G");
                                                }else
                                                {
                                                    Log.d("TAG", "Error al subir url G");
                                                }


                                            }
                                        }); 





                                }
                            });
                    referenciaPictos.putStream(p).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrlP = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

    mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("URL_p").setValue(downloadUrlP.toString(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference referenciaP) {
            if(referenciaP!=null){

                Log.d("TAG", "Se guardo correctamente url P");
            }else{
                Log.d("TAG", "Error al subir url P");
            }



        }
    }); 



                        }
                    });
                    referenciaF.putStream(fG).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrlF = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();


                                mDatabase.child("User").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("URL_f").setValue(downloadUrlF.toString(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference referenciaF) {
                                        if(referenciaF!=null){
                                            Log.d("TAG", "Se guardo correctamente url F");
                                        }else{

                                            Log.d("TAG", "Error al subir url F");
                                        }

                                    }
                                });




                        }
                    });


                   }else{
                       Log.d("TAG","El usuario es null");
                       Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR, SUBIENDO ARCHIVOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the current user is null before saving any data.

```
 myref.putStream(groups)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrlGrupos = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                                mDatabase.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("groups").setValue(downloadUrlGrupos.toString(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference groupsReference) {
                                        if (groupsReference != null) {
                                            Log.d("TAG", "Se guardo correctamente url Grupos");
                                        } else {
                                            Log.d("TAG", "Error al subir url Grupos");
                                        }


                                    }
                                });
                            }


                        }
                    });
```

Comment: yes, i do it right after onStop , i have all the references with that, but it seems it keeps crashing

Comment: Can you upload the whole code? Including your onStop method

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do two things.

1. Set a flag for upload.
   Before upload starts you can put a flag. Once upload finishes set the flag to be removed by the firebase callback function. So while the flag is on don't let the Sign Out button to be clicked.
2. Set a flag for SignOut.
   When you click the SignOut button a flag gets turn on. After each upload request in the callback function check the flag. If the flag is on make the SignOut work.

My opinion is first method is more general than second one. But second one  more close to the asynchronous nature in Firebase.